# How to give name to a figure in processing language of data visualisation?

Tags: processing, data-visualization

I am using processing language to visualize A* algorithm(to find optimal path between start and end city).

Each city is displayed as a point but I want to name it and I couldn't find any way to do so.

Also, I would like to set style for name as in font-size, color, font-weight.

Please let me know.

Edit:
Below is a code snippet, I have city name in string currCity and it's location in a list of Double values(it just has 2 values, one is x' axis and other is y' axis). By using this location, I am able to plot the point but don't know how to name it. 
 Basically I have a map for all cities where key is city name(unique in my case) and value is a list of cordinates. I am iterating over each key

```
String currCity = currEntry.getKey();
List<Double> currLocationList = currEntry.getValue(); 
stroke(255);
ellipse(currLocationList.get(0).intValue(), currLocationList.get(1).intValue(), w, h);
//w, h is width and height of circle (I am setting as just 1 to draw a point)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to put a visual label against some points? That _really_ depends on what visualisation tool you are using

Comment: Yaah, against each point with respect to city name that corresponds to it. I am using Processing and have integrated it in Eclipse for Java.

Comment: Wow that's such a generic name! I thought processing was just some generic tag but as you point out, it's the platform you're using. I guess this is it: https://processing.org/  Well if you have any kind of existing code, you really need to post it

Comment: Edited, sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

> I want to name it and I couldn't find any way to do so.

You can display text using the `text()` function.

> Also, I would like to set style for name as in font-size, color, font-weight.

See the `textSize()` function, the `fill()` and `stroke()` functions, and the various **Typography** functions.

Comment: That works, I checked for it randomly on web but couldn't find these methods. Thanks Sir